# A question on multiplicity of complex polynomial

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, polynomials

This is not a research level question. But due to some reason I can't ask this question on Math Stack Exchange. So, I am asking this question here.

By definition we know that we can measure the multiplicity of a root of a function $f(z)$ as follow.

If the a root of some function $f(z)$ is $\alpha_i$, then the multiplicity of that root is $a_i$ for which $\lim \limits_{x \to \alpha_i} |\frac{f(z)}{(z-\alpha_i)^{a_i}}|$ has a finite value.

So, following this we can see that all the roots ($(2n+1)i\pi$, 
) of the polynomial $e^z+1$ has multiplicity $1$.

So, $$e^z+1= 2\prod_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z}{(2n+1)i\pi}\right)$$.....(1)

Which further can be written as

$$e^z+1= 2\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{z^2}{((2n+1)i\pi)^2}\right)$$

But this only consists of $z^{2k}$ not the odd powers.

If we directly check this from (1) we see the coefficients of $z^3$, we see they are $0$ which can be directly concluded from (1).

But actually $e^z+1=2+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+....$. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ...$e^z + 1$ is not a polynomial. Some food for further thought: what are the zeroes of $e^z$, and can it be represented in a similar way?

Comment: I got my answer. And voted to delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your product on the right does not converge for any $z \neq 0.$ Never fear, [the Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) is your friend.